# Cypher set where condition only one relation can show of each node in the path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I got a graph with circular type relationship. So there may have two different direction relationships (outgoing and incoming) between each node in my graph. I am trying to find the path between two nodes without using `shortestpath()`. How to give the condition to set only 1 relationship will show between each node in the path? Here is my query:

```
Match p = (A)-[r*]-(b) return p
```

What should I write for where part?

Comment: First, if you don't use shortestpath(), you need to cap your [r*] so that the query doesn't pull up infinite paths. Also are you trying to find all paths that uses each edge only once?

Comment: I am trying to find the shortest distance between two nodes. I have distance property in my relationships type GO_TO. I think it should be only once but not all edges. For example, I have two nodes A,B  and I also have two relationships GO_TO between A,B(incoming and outgoing)  I only want outgoing direction show in my path. So when I query the path between A-F. It should only show **A->B->C->D->E->F** 
@Tezra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what yo really want is shortest weighted path. Cypher doesn't directly support this yet, but you can query it like this

```
MATCH (start:Point {id: '1'}), (end:Point {id: '2'})
MATCH p=(start)-[:GO_TO*1..25]->(end)
WITH p,reduce(s = 0, r IN rels(p) | s + r.myValueProp) AS dist
RETURN p, dist ORDER BY dist DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct way to get my answer. But when I have huge relationships and nodes. it will have the huge result which will make my query into the infinite loop.So that's why I want to set relation direction into one direction @Terze

Comment: @LinBernie That is also why I cap the number of nodes (to 25) that it can use in paths. The lower the cap, the better the performance, but it might also then miss some better path.